# formula in R name string

Tags: r

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
      country company hitid
 1 Switzerland     CH1  <NA>
 2 Switzerland     CH2  <NA>
 3 Switzerland     CH3  <NA>
 4      Sweden     SU1  <NA>
 5      Sweden     SU2  <NA>
 6      Sweden     SU3  <NA>
```

in the hitid collumn, I would like to fill in automatically results of a loop I have run before. The results are given in the form d$COUNTRY$hitid, where for each country, I have got another hitid that I would like to fill in.

EDIT: 
my loop output is of the following form:

```
$Switzerland
    HITTypeId        HITId          Valid
1   1010               123           TRUE

$Sweden
   HITTypeId      HITId        Valid
1 1010            456           TRUE
```

Is there any way that one can use a formula inside of a name string? That i could construct something like:

```
hitid=d$"formula to look up country"$hitid
```

Or any ideas how to construct this problem more elegant?

Basically I just want to extract the HITId for each country out of the loop and into the existing datfile.

Comment: I don't think you are doing it the right way, but it's difficult to say without being able to see what you call "results of a loop I have run before". You could copy/paste it on your question, and maybe provide the desired final output ?

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to do, but in general `[[` is more flexible than `$`. See if `?"["` gives you any ideas.

Comment: post an example of your loop results into a code block in your question. Something like `str(myloopresults`) will be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a `plyr` solution.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(country),transform,
                hitid=  d[[unique(country)]]$hitid)
```

Where I assume that :

```
d <- list(Switzerland=list(hitid=1),
          Sweden=list(hitid=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes some assumptions about your data, i.e., that `DF$country` is a character column and that `d` is a list.

```
DF <- read.table(text="      country company hitid
 1 Switzerland     CH1  <NA>
 2 Switzerland     CH2  <NA>
 3 Switzerland     CH3  <NA>
 4      Sweden     SU1  <NA>
 5      Sweden     SU2  <NA>
 6      Sweden     SU3  <NA>",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d <- list(Switzerland=list(hitid=123),Sweden=list(hitid=456))

fun <- function(x) d[[x]][["hitid"]]
DF$hitid <- sapply(DF$country,fun)

#       country company hitid
# 1 Switzerland     CH1   123
# 2 Switzerland     CH2   123
# 3 Switzerland     CH3   123
# 4      Sweden     SU1   456
# 5      Sweden     SU2   456
# 6      Sweden     SU3   456
```